# What stands for lpfnWndProc?

Tags: api, winapi

I know 
lp = long pointer
WndProc = Windows Procedure

but I dunno what is fn. fn stands for what?

```
WNDCLASS wndClass;
wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
```

Comment: Have you considered "Function"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

fn = Function.  lpfnWndProc = Long Pointer to the Windows Procedure function.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> lpfnWndProc
>
> Type: WNDPROC
>
> A pointer to the window procedure. You must use the CallWindowProc function to call the window procedure. For more information, see WindowProc.

Answer (score 0):

'fn' means function. You're right about the 'lp' meaning 'long pointer'